# How to send android xml to php web service in order to send email using web service android

Tags: android, xml, web-services, email

I need to send xml(designed in android) to php web service and then need to use web service to send email and also want to get the response of email in json 
i am a beginner in android so please help me ...
thanks

Comment: I don't know how to send whole XML file to web service but you can insert data in XML in to JSON array and send to server is possible.If you need i will show you example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    public JSONParser() {

    }
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List<NameValuePair> params) {


        try {
            if(method == "POST"){
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }


        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Then Create AsyncTask Class to upload data to server.Then add this code.

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String message="";        
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value1", value1));

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(SERVER_URL,
                "POST", params);
        try {
                message=json.getString("message");
                Log.e("msg",message);

        }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return message ;
    }
```

value1 send to server.

Answer (score 0):

You can haz teh code

```
/*
* Getting the XML ready for sending
*/
String xml = getXml(); // YOUR XML STRING  
List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nvps.add( new BasicNameValuePair("XML",xml) );
/*
* Getting ready to send and receive from server
*/
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("/your/service/url");
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFromEntity(nvps));
post.addHeader("Content-Type","application/xml");
post.addHeader("Accept","application/json");
/*
* Sending the file and waiting for response
*/
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
/*
* Getting the JSON from the response
*/
if( response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200 ){
    String json = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    // PROCESS RESPONSE HERE
}
```

Please note that I wrote this from memory. I may have made mistakes here and there.  You can now use `GSON` to deserialize the JSON you received in response.