# Connect HttpsUrlConnect with Asynctask and get JSON on Android

Tags: android, json, https, android-asynctask

==============

### I need help. I'm doing an app with Android.

- Firstly i need to connect via Https in this url: 
  https://e-sketchapi.cadt.com/cgi-bin/share/json/rpc.pjson

To interact with it i need to use this arguments:

`SketchAPI.Login(“username”=><username>,”password”=><password>)`

This method return:

```
{"err":0,"dt":{"username":"XXXX","uid":"0","perms":{"Carta":
["basic"],"container.cadt.com":["basic"],"download.cadt.com" ["basic"],"esketchapi.
cadt.com":["basic"],"ldst.cadt.com":["basic"],"madima.cadt.com":
["basic"],"prodcontrol.cadt.com":["basic"],"cloud.cadt.com":
["basic"]},"session":"XXXXX","session_exp
ires":1420805985}}`
```

> In CURL PHP is like this:

```
function sendPost($url,$fn,$args=null) {

$param = array( 'fn' => $fn, 'args' => $args);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($param));

$result = curl_exec ($ch); 
curl_close ($ch); 

return $result;
}

$user="XXXX";
$pass="XXXX";
$sessid="";
//set POST variables
$url = 'https://e-sketchapi.cadt.com/cgi-bin/share/json/rpc.pjson';
$fn  = 'SketchAPI.Login';


$args = array('username'=>$user,'passwd'=>$pass);

//url-ify the data for the POST


$ret = sendPost($url,$fn,$args);

print ("[".$ret."]\n");
```

> How will be for Android?

**I have:**

Layout activity_main.xml

Button

When I click on a button, it shows another layout which shows you the information of json parameters that you have introduced using method

```
SketchAPI.Login(“username”=><username>,”password”=><password>)
```

**How is in mainActivity.java?**

In my AndroidManifest i have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: Nicely written ... but you forgot to write most important thing: what did you already tried on Android side ... there is a pleanty tutorials/code samples over internet for topic: how to post json ... SO is not PHP to Java translation service.

Answer (score -2):

```
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    public JSONParser() {

    }
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List<NameValuePair> params) {


        try {
            if(method == "POST"){
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }


        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Then Create AsyncTask Class to upload data to server.Then add this in to doingBackground method  code.

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String message="";        
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value1", value1));

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(SERVER_URL,
                "POST", params);
        try {
                message=json.getString("message");
                Log.e("msg",message);

        }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return message ;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: it will send data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` not `text/json`

Comment: also i see that this is your universal answer ... hehe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405216/web-service-in-android-doesnot-send-the-value-to-the-server#answer-27405577 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27334660/how-to-send-android-xml-to-php-web-service-in-order-to-send-email-using-web-serv#answer-27334942

Comment: well, actually yes, it is a matter, as this code not apply here ... see my first comment ...

Comment: Ok i thought you have used json.That is why i posted.